# overwrite a function in parent theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a function on parent theme called function ce_seller_bar( $seller )

I want to overwrite it in child theme without deleting it from parent

When I delete it in parent theme it works, when I don't delete it the browser output is:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ce_seller_bar()
>        (previously declared in
>          C:\wamp\www\CampusAdsList2\wp-content\themes\classifiedengine-child 
>                                        \includes\template.php:12)

That means that child function had been loaded before parent one 
so I want to write the function in child theme so after update I dont lose it

ty

Comment: This is exactly what I would expect to happen. You can't have two functions with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

**thanks for replay**
I took a nap when I woke up,I figured out an easy solution 
my solution is to overwirte file /template/ad_detail.php that calls this function and this file doesnt contain functions like template.php so I copy and past it in child theme directory
as I created my new function with defferent name in fuctions.php in child theme as well as I call  it new file in /template/ad_detail.php inside child theme and it works fine for me